# How to adjust the knot on tefillin shel rosh? (double daled)

Tags: tefilin, how-to, tying-knots-kosheir

Sometimes the knot on the *tefillin shel rosh* needs to be adjusted, either due to growth, haircut, or borrowing a pair of tefillin.

**How is that knot adjusted?**
What piece of the *retzuah* (strap) should be pulled, in which direction? How would you make it bigger or smaller?

> This question is about the **double *daled* knot**. For the single *daled* knot, see [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/47767/5323).

Comment: Are all double dalet knots the same?

Comment: @Yishai I assume so. Do you know something that I don't?

Comment: Shokhet, No, just my default assumption wouldn't be that this is the case.

Comment: @Yishai All right, then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [this page on Tiferes Stam](http://www.tiferes.com/index.php?route=information/information&information_id=10), which shows a diagram with instructions for both the double- and single-daled knots, as well as information about how the *tefillin* should fit. The instructions for tightening the double-daled knot are:

[image: 3-part diagram of the tightening process for the "double-daled" knot, with the knot oriented so that one of the free straps hangs down on the bottom-right. 1) Opening a loop on the bottom-left by pulling down. 2) Transferring the slack from the bottom-left to the top-right, moving the loop to the top- right. 3) Closing the loop by pulling the free strap on the bottom-right.]

> Say לשם קדושת תפילין, then
>
> 1. Pull the strap marked with the arrow down, making  the head loop smaller
> 2. Close the loop you just made under the knot by pulling up from behind (direction of  arrow).
> 3. Close the second loop, made in step 2, by pulling down on the free-hanging part of the strap.
> 4. Kesher is complete.